# OpenStack: Assigning IPs manually

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, openstack

I am deploying OpenStack Havana over Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS following the official documentation (http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/index.html). I'm using a single-node installation, so one physical machine is acting as controller node and compute node at the same time.

Right now I have everything working except for the network. I should remark that I am not using Neutron, just Nova Network. Also, I should say I'm far from being a networking expert.

The problem is the next one: in my enterprise, as far as I know, every device has a public IP. This is, there are no IPs such as 192.168.X.X or 10.0.X.X. Rather, all IPs are located in a public subnet, to say, A.B.0.0/16. In particular, my department has the subnet A.B.C.0/24 assigned, so all our devices should be assigned an IP in that range. The gateway has assigned the IP A.B.C.2.

So far, I have not been able to configure the network correctly. What I would like to do is the following:

- Using, *nova network create*, create a new network which is the same one that the physical machine:

  ```
  nova network-create vmnet --fixed-range-v4=A.B.C.0/24 --gateway=A.B.C.2 --dns1=8.8.8.8 --dns2=4.4.4.4
  ```
- Then, assign IPs manually to each virtual machine. If IPs were assigned in that subnet, it would override other IPs from existing computers. So what I would like is doing pretty much what I can do with VirtualBox when I setup the adapter as a "Bridge Adapter", i.e., assigning an IP manually in the guest OS.

Is that even possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First I have to tell you it is possible to do so in Openstack.

Comment: But before I can help you we need to understand what you really need. If Openstack is really necessary then go for neutron-network instead of nova-network. Next step is to go for flat-networking [http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/section_neutron-single-flat.html] (explained here). The configuration simply can not be explained with words, but If you follow the docs and know what you are doing it can be done.However having instances in the same network as host can be much easily done using LXC as well.

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow that instructions. Regarding OpenStack, it is an external constraint, so I cannot really make a decision there. I'll go with Neutron and try.

Comment: Follow the configurations in my answer. If you run into problems get back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Neutron network and specifically go for ovs plugin. Because the instructions I am giving below will only work for it.

You have to setup the ovs plugin with the following configuration in '/etc/neutron/plugins/openvswitch/ovs_neutron_plugin.ini'

```
[OVS]
tenant_network_type = gre
network_vlan_ranges = EXTNet
enable_tunneling = True
tunnel_type = gre
tunnel_id_ranges = 1:1000
integration_bridge = br-int
tunnel_bridge = br-tun
bridge_mappings = EXTNet:br-ex
local_ip = <your machine IP here>
```

Note the Bridge mappings entry. It maps the **EXTNet** to br-ex. Later you will use this EXTNet as provider physical network while creating your network in Openstack. For now you have to add one of your host's interfaces that is connected to your enterprise networks to br-ex. After adding it you may not be able to access your host through that interface so always use a secondary interface for this.

Once you are done with the setup do the following.

```
quantum net-create EXTNet --provider:physical_network EXTNet --provider:network_type flat 
quantum net-update EXTNet --router:external True
quantum net-update EXTNet --shared True
quantum subnet-create --name EXTSubnet --gateway <external network gateway> EXTNet    <external network CIDR> --enable_dhcp False
```

There may be other ways of doing. But I have tested this approach and hence recommend.

Once you have successfully created a subnet, just lauch instances in it.

One thing to note here is since you have disabled dhcp in your subnet openstack will not run dnsmasq on it ahd hence you should have to provide your own dhcp server.

Second since the network_type is flat there wont be any vlan packets. The packets from your instance will flow as it is on your external network, which is what you want.

Comment: Hi @Akilesh! I first installed neutron following the OpenStack install guide. Unfortunately, it's not as clear as the previous chapters, but still I think I did it correctly. I followed the steps for _Installing networking support on a dedicated controller node_ and then those for a compute node. Then I created the network following your instructions (just changing `quantum` by `neutron`). Now I can create instances ending up in error, and which I cannot delete (unless using `nova-network` again rather than Neutron)

Comment: Finally, I think I've seen in some screenshot support for Neutron in OpenStack Dashboard (Horizon), with functionality for managing networks from the UI. Do you know how it can be installed? Thanks.

Comment: sorry for delay. installing open stack dashboard is as easy as installing a package with the same name in Ubuntu. but I have to warn you not everything that can be done from CLI can be done from dashboard. second its quiet common to run into problems while launching but that can be resolved by looking into nova api logs.

Comment: switching back to nova is not encouraging. it reduces your options. if you are game then we can agree on a common time to resolve this for you with neutron network. I have done it a dozen times.

Comment: I already had Horizon installed, just wondering whether Neutron management could be done from there (some screenshots I've seen suggest it is possible). But that's not important.
I have a script which I use to deploy OpenStack in a fresh Ubuntu 12.04, just Keystone, Glance and Nova, so I can get there pretty easily. Then, I'm trying to extend the script to install and configure Neutron, maybe you could help me there. I'm in UTC+1, maybe we could arrange some meeting? Probably there is some minor configuration issue. Regards!